# Model DOM sub-trees in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dom, types

How could I write a type-safe function that accepts (e.g.) an [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) with two [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) children, one of them of type `number` and the other of type `text` and optional?

I don't know if this is even possible, but it would be highly beneficial for writing any DOM-manipulating function. Either way, what other approaches would you take to implement functions like the one described above?

Comment: How can the HTMLInputElement child be HTMLInputElement  if it's also a number?

Comment: What I meant is an `HTMLInputElement` whose type attribute is "number". Although it would certainly be interesting to have a way of saying that the value property of an input is a number, so that you could operate with it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to statically validate runtime behaviour, which is not possible.

In other words, you're trying to write a function that should determine at compile time the state of the dom, which is not known until you're actually running the code.

You could instead write a function which accepts the form and the two inputs, and do some extra validation at runtime, if the types are important.

```
function myBehaviour(
    form: HTMLFormElement,
    inputNumber: HTMLInputElement,
    optionalText: HTMLInputElement
) {
    if (inputNumber.type != 'number') throw new Error(...);
    if (optionalText.type == 'text' && !optionalText.required) throw new Error(...);
}
```

If I was to write this kind of code for an app, I would conditionally enable these assertions in the development / test build of the app and omit them from the production.

Comment: Not sure I see your point when you talk about runtime vs compile time... Trying to find an analogue case, you may have a tuple of type `[number, boolean]` without value, and later on your program (at runtime) set values to it. As long as you use indexes to refer to the individual values, everything will be checked by the compiler.

I should clarify I don't intend to accept DOM nodes from the wild, but rather nodes created in code. Do you have any idea of how to achieve type safety in that case?

About the input of type number, it occurred to me to extend the native element -- goo.gl/ME9A9y